# How to regain control of the command prompt after starting a Rails server on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, command-prompt

I know in Unix if you start the server like this:

```
rails server &
```

and after starting the server, you still have the same cmd window available to you. But on Windows this doesn't seem to work. Can I do something similar in Windows?

Comment: "Regain control" means?

Comment: When you start the rails server in a cmd windows you can no longer use the same windows for writing other command, for example, change directory, generate controller etc., so you have to start a new cmd window. In Unix if you start the rails server with the "&" switch you can execute commands in the same windows after the server has started.

Comment: On the one hand, your question is intellectually valid, on the other hand, I have to wonder why you want to do everything in the same window. I mean, command windows are cheap, you can use lots of them.

Comment: I was watching a course and so the instructor do this on a Mac. I tried it in Windows but it didn't work, so I wondered what would be the alternative. Otherwise you are right, I can have two windows without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run server with deamon in windows :

```
rails server -d

or 

rails s -d
```

it will start rails server in background.

Comment: I thought that would be the answer and probably is. The only problem I have is that I get: "daemon() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this :

```
start rails server
```

Your question has also been investigated on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/39451/there-is-any-way-to-run-processes-in-the-background-in-windows-nohup-equivalent), with no clear cut answer as far as I can tell. The `start` command seems to be the closest thing, if the scenario is that you're hacking away at the command prompt and you need to start something up and have it out of your way.

Comment: That just opens a new cmd window where the rails server is started.

Comment: With the /B flag then ?

Comment: With the B flag nothing happens - the server isn't started in the current or in a new window.

Comment: Updated my answer with links to related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am using grails, so not many ideas about ruby.But I regain control using `ctrl+c` or `ctrl+d`.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: If you press control ctrl+c you stop the server - I don't want to do that. ctrl+d doesn't do anything.